# remove www in htaccess for directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, no-www

I have a website that I have created on one of its folders. Now I want to delete the site with the command.
My page is located [here](https://matdesign.ir/charge)

Answer (score 0):

if I've understood your question (and please make it more clear this time and next times :) ) you can do it like this :

```
sudo rm .htaccess
```

Or

```
rm -rf Name-of-your-file
```

have a nice iranian day !

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.matdesign\.ir
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/matdesign\.ir\/" [R=301,L]
______
I've put the code above for you. All I do not know here is adding a directory to the code if it's possible to tell me where to place the charge.

Comment: I don't think you are getting there by .htacess, just delete the directory containing the "charge", not from .htaccess file. and there you have it.

Comment: I've already fixed the site problem with the same method. I will share the code for you. My tip of your response.

Comment: I'm glad that you solved this just post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.ir%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^(https?://)www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [L,R,QSA]
```

first code : delete http and set to https and
next code : delete https://www and set to https://